# 7404N and high output

Tags: digital-logic

Simple question: Is it OK for the output pins to be high? I want to use the 7401N together with a 74LS138 to do memory address decoding. I will connect two Yx pins to two two separate input pins on the 7404N. From here the two output pins from the 7404N will be connected to the same pin on my Micro-Kim (the /DEN pin). Will that fry the 7404N?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fco434.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Regards, Jacob

Comment: please add a schematic of what you intend

Comment: Is there a free web service where I can make that easily?

Comment: Just click 'edit' on your question and there is a circuit editor and simulator app available right there.

Comment: Woah - that's neat! I have made one - just know that I am a total noob regarding electronics - you'll probably laugh at my attempt :-)

Comment: It's unconventional, but clear what you meant in your question now.

Comment: You should include a truth table. It is not clear under what conditions you want to enable the Micro-Kim expansion port. You are aware that the 74LS138's outputs are active-low aren't you?

Comment: Sorry - this is my first attempt at digital electronics - at electronics, even. Now that you mention the active-low thing I am starting to wonder if I even need the 7404. I'll give it some more thought but no matter what I have learned a bunch here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing with the two outputs is not okay.

Basically if one of them wants to be high and the other wants to be low, they will compete and force limiting currents through each other, very likely damaging them, because you cannot guarantee in any case that they will go high or low at the same time, since then you'd have to tie both inputs together as well.

Depending on what you want to do exactly (not sufficiently clearly specified for me), in the sense of combining them you need OR, or AND, or NOR, or NAND gates, or diodes and/or transistors to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had a feeling that this was the case. So if I put a diode between 1Y and /DEN and between 6Y and /DEN there will be no problem?

Comment: Since the 74LS138 has active low outputs, the Y0 and Y7 outputs will never both be low at the same time. Therefore you can eliminate OR and NOR as possibilities. I'm guessing AND is what he needs, but NAND is a possibility since the OP did not include a truth table.

Comment: @jriff small signal diodes will do the trick, as long as you then also include a pull down resistor.

Comment: @Tut Fair enough. But I'm too lazy to edit, I'm just going to consider that last comment as over-completeness :-)

Comment: No problem. The comment was really more for the OP's benefit to help him work out his logic.

Answer (score 1):

No that won't work. You can't wire two outputs together like that.

You should combine them with some sort of logic function eg 'Or' 7432, 'And' 7408 or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And thank you for teaching me how to ask questions here :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll fry anything, but since 7404s aren't open-collector gates, if you connect two outputs together and they're not both high or low at the same time, the output logic level will be undefined and can't be guaranteed to be either a 1 or a zero.

Following is the 7404 schematic from [TI's data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf) so you can see what's going on in there, and what logic function do you want to implement?

Or, better yet, can you complete this truth table?:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Can you explain to me why it won't work? (I'm a noob here). If both outputs are 1 (5V) wouldn't they combined still be 5V? And if they are both low (<0.8V) wouldn't they combined be low? I'm not doubting your answer - I just don't understand why :-)

Comment: @jriff:  If they're **not** both high or low at the same time...  That is, if one is high and the other is low. :)

Comment: You are right - didn't think about that combination :-)

Comment: Truth table: 

0 0 = 0 | 
0 1 = 0 | 
1 0 = 0 | 
1 1 = 1

Comment: I'm thinking that I can just use a 4071? That is a NAND with a NOT, right?

Comment: BTW. I am now learning that there are two different kinds of components - TTL and CMOS. I didn't know. Do they work fine together? What I read about it seems to be a bit confusing.

Comment: A 4071 is four 2 input OR gates, each of which will  output a low only when **both** of its inputs are low.   Your truth table shows that you want /DEN to go low when **either** Y0 or Y7 is low, so that's one of the gates in a  4081 or a 7408,  which comprise  four AND gates.

Comment: TTL is an acronym for "Transistor Transistor Logic" originally used to specify  the input and output voltage thresholds corresponding to a logical "1" or "0" in TI's  74XX family of bipolar logic. Since then its meaning has come to include any logic device compatible with those criteria.  CMOS has different thresholds, and while it can drive TTL inputs directly, it cannot be driven by TTL outputs unless the TTL inputs are weakly pulled up to the logic supply voltage through a resistor.  A notable exception is 74HCT, a logic family which was designed expressly to be TTL compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [7407](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7407.pdf) instead of the 7404.  The 7407 has [open-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) outputs.  Tying the two outputs together in this fashion is called a "[wired-or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection#The_wired_OR_connection)" or "[wired-and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection#The_wired_AND_connection)" depending on the polarity of the signals (the latter in this case, because the outputs of the '138 are active low).

So there won't be a conflict if one  output of the 7407 is high and the other is low. With the 7404, this situation would cause a short since +5 would be connected directly to ground.

You will want to add a pullup resistor to the output line to +5V to provide the high level.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning open-collector. I didn't know about that concept and will read up on it. Sounds like what I need.

Comment: @Tut   I disagree.  The unasserted state is both outputs high, so /DEN will be high.  /DEN goes low only when one of the outputs goes low.  I should have called it a wired-AND, even though it's performing an OR function with inverted logic.  Corrected my answer.

Comment: @Tut yes, you're right, forgot the '06 was inverting.  Will switch to use the '07. Thanks for the correction.